# How to make the text color to change back and forth automatically using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, colors

```
<div>
<h2 id="change"> Hello Family</h2>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
setTimeout("firstColor()", 3000)
function firstColor(){
document.getElementById('change').style.color="#ffffff";
secondColor();
}

function secondColor(){
document.getElementById('change').style.color="#33ccff";
}
</script>
```

This code only changes the color once. I want the two colors to change back and forth.  When I call the `secondColor` function from the `firstColor` function, it does not execute. I know what I have so far is not a loop, but I am puzzled with the fact that the `secondColor()` will not execute.  I need help understanding why the `secondColor` function is not executing and how to loop it.

Answer (score 1):

By calling `secondColor()` in your first method, you are setting the second color before the screen gets a chance of rendering the first color. You have to leave a timeout between both.

So, I would recommend a general approach more like this:

```
var myToggle = false;

setTimeout(function() {

   if (myToggle) {
       document.getElementById('change').style.color="#ffffff"
   }
   else {
       document.getElementById('change').style.color="#33ccff";
   }

   myToggle = !myToggle;

}, 3000)
```